# Override Wordpress Filter Priority

Tags: wordpress

I want to override all the other action filters, and give highest priority to my custom filter. Some plugins , which also add custom filters to `the_content`.And those plugins also use '**PHP_INT_MAX**' priority level.

```
add_filter('the_content','comments_container_main',PHP_INT_MAX+1);
```

Is this fine, using '**PHP_INT_MAX+1**' as priority level.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
add_filter('the_content','comments_container_main',99);
```

Hope it will work

Comment: Thanks @Ravi Kumar . It overrides most other custom filters.but there are still some filters in which  **PHP_INT_MAX** is used.

Comment: Try to use 9999999999 instead of 99

Comment: the other thing is you can use remove_filter('the_content','comments_container_main',99); and try to add your new filter

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.